# Passing variables to UiCollectionViewLayout in Swift

Tags: swift

Can someone please assist.  I am trying to pass a variable from a UICollectionViewController.swift to a UiCollectionViewLayout.swift in swift. I have tried delegates, but I am unsure where to assign the delegate (usually done in the PrepareForSeque method, which is not called when the UiCollectionViewLayout class is used as far as I know).  Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Your UICollectionViewController has a reference to your UICollectionView (see [collectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewController/collectionView)). So create vars in your UICollectionViewLayout subclass and set them directly from your UICollectionViewController.